# RJAGS - Zero Inflated Negative Binomial RJAGS

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation, jags

I am trying to fit a RJAGS zero-inflated negative binomial model. The data I am using has 451 observation and only 12 of them have values different to 0, which means that 97% of my observations are 0. My objective is obtaining the the posterior distribution of the probability of the data belonging to the non-structural zero $\pi$, the expected value of the negative binomial part $\mu$ and the size parameter $r$. My data is distributed as:
[image]

I have created a model in RJAGS with the following structure:

```
negativebinom <-"model {
  # Likelihood
  for (i in 1:length(Y)) {
    Y[i] ~ dnegbin(p1[i],r)
    p1[i]=r/(r+mu1[i])
    mu1[i]=z[i]*mu
    z[i]~dbern(pro)
    
    
  }
  
  log(mu)=eta
  pro=1-zero.prob
  logit(zero.prob)=theta
  theta~dnorm(2,1)
  eta~dgamma(1.2,0.7)
  r ~ dnorm(7.280611e+06,1.430766e+04)
}"
```

Where $Y$ stands for the count variable, $r$ the size parameter of the negative binomial, $p1$ is the probability parameters of each observation which depends on $\mu_1$.  $\mu_1$ is the expected value of each observation which depends on $z$ a Bernoulli variable modelling if we are in the non-structural zero part or not. $z$ takes value 0 if Y is 0 and 1 otherwise. However, I think I am forcing the model to consider all 0's part of the non-structural 0 and not leaving any chance for them to be generated by the negative binomial part. In fact, while computing the posterior distribution probability zero.pro, which should be the probability of non-structural zero, is the same or matches with the actual proportion of 0's of our data:
[image]

What should I modify in my model to make this probability modelling the non-structural zero probability and not the overall probability of being zero?